# Eclipse Progress Dialog remains minimized

Tags: eclipse

A while ago, I started a job in an Eclipse app which consequently showed a progress bar. I then decided to let it 'Run In Background' which minimized it to the statusbar where the progress was showed. When I tried to bring it back to the foreground, it did nothing. Restarting the app showed the dialog again (although not a solution) on other machines, but in my case the dialog is permanently minimized. This happens when running it out of Eclipse and running the app's executable.

Is there anything local to my machine that I can look at? I tried finding something in the AppData folder & Registry, but to no avail. It's only my machine, so I don't think any code will help and it is also an 'established' app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Preferences > General` and unselect the `Always run in background` check box.

If you don't have the preference page in your app the setting is saved as

```
RUN_IN_BACKGROUND=true
```

in the `org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs` file in the `.metadata/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` directory of the workspace.